# ReactJs how to show list with load more option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am tring to show todo list with load more option. I am appling limit.Limit is apply to list.But when i add loadmore()function. then i get error **this.state.limit is null** Wher i am wrong.Any one can suggest me.
here is my code
todoList.jsx

```
var TodoList=React.createClass({
    render:function(){
    var {todos}=this.props;
    var limit = 5;

    function onLoadMore() {
        this.setState({
            limit: this.state.limit + 5
        });
    }
    var renderTodos=()=>{
            return todos.slice(0,this.state.limit).map((todo)=>{
                return(
                        <Todo key={todo.todo_id}{...todo} onToggle={this.props.onToggle}/>
                );
            });

    };

    return(
        <div>
            {renderTodos()}
            <a href="#" onClick={this.onLoadMore}>Load</a>
        </div>
        )
}
});
module.exports=TodoList;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Changes:**

**1.** First define the `limit` in `state` variable by using `getInitialState` method, you didn't define the limit, that's why `this.state.limit` is `null`.

**2.** Define all the `functions` outside of the `render` method.

**3.** `Arrow function` with `renderTodos` is not required.

**4.** Use `this` keyword to call the `renderTodos` method like this:

```
{this.renderTodos()}
```

Write it like this:

```
var TodoList=React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            limit: 5
        }
    },

    onLoadMore() {
        this.setState({
            limit: this.state.limit + 5
        });
    },

    renderTodos: function(){
        return todos.slice(0,this.state.limit).map((todo)=>{
            return(
                <Todo key={todo.todo_id}{...todo} onToggle={this.props.onToggle}/>
            );
        });
    };

    render:function(){
        var {todos} = this.props;
        return(
            <div>
                {this.renderTodos()}
                <a href="#" onClick={this.onLoadMore}>Load</a>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Mayank Shukla sir

Comment: The problem with this approach is that all todos up to `limit` will get rendered. Suppose you have a list of books, each with it's own image etc. Each time the load more button is clicked will render them all. Any suggestion on how to render only added items?

Comment: we can use `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method in `Todo` component, and skips the rendering of old items.

Comment: ```.filter((e,i) => i>=0 && i<=this.state.limit)```

better use this to prevent the bug in mobile

Comment: can you please edit answer with functional component as well ?

Answer (score 0):

This is witout button click.

As you all know react components has a function `componentDidMount()` which gets called automatically when the template of that component is rendered into the DOM. And I have used the same function to add the event listener for scroll into our div iScroll. 
The `scrollTop` property of the element will find the scroll position and add it with the `clientHeight` property. 
Next, the if condition will check the addition of these two properties is greater or equal to the scroll-bar height or not. If the condition is true the `loadMoreItems` function will run.

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      items: 10,
      loadingState: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.iScroll.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      if (this.refs.iScroll.scrollTop + this.refs.iScroll.clientHeight >=this.refs.iScroll.scrollHeight){
        this.loadMoreItems();
      }
    });
  }

  displayItems() {
    var items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items; i++) {
      items.push(<li key={i}>Item {i}</li>);
    }
    return items;
  }

  loadMoreItems() {
    this.setState({ loadingState: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ items: this.state.items + 10, loadingState: false });
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref="iScroll" style={{ height: "200px", overflow: "auto" }}>
        <ul>
          {this.displayItems()}
        </ul>

        {this.state.loadingState ? <p className="loading"> loading More Items..</p> : ""}

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[This is example](http://voidcanvas.com/implementing-infinite-scroll-with-react-js-without-plugin/)