# How to only return first 10 results of JSON data with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pull just the first 10 entries in a JSON file (id's 1 - 10). Looking to see if that is possible to do with my below code and what the best method would be. I'm looking to control the amount displayed to the first 10 results and add a button to load 10 more (id's 11 - 20, etc.)

Here is how I'm pulling the results in:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PostData from '../data/posts.json'

    class PostList extends Component {
      render () {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            {PostData.map((postDetail, index) => {
              return <h2>{postDetailDetail.title}</h2>
            })}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

And here is a snapshot of the posts.json file (not full):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Hello World",
    "content": "content goes here",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Hello React",
    "content": "another content goes here",
  },
  // ...continued entries. Cut off to save space.
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJs how to show list with load more option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071679/reactjs-how-to-show-list-with-load-more-option)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
 {PostData.map((postDetail, index) => {
     return index <= 9 ? <h2>{postDetailDetail.title}</h2> : undefined
 })}
```

This will only return the html if the index is less than or equal to 9 (which is the 10th position since it starts with 0)

And here is a full example with the increase button

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PostData from '../data/posts.json'

class PostList extends Component {

    state = {showCount: 10}

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                
                {PostData.map((postDetail, index) => {
                    return index + 1 <= showCount ? <h2>{postDetailDetail.title}</h2> : undefined
                })}
                <button 
                    onClick={() => this.setState(prevState => {
                        showCount: prevState.showCount + 10
                    })}>
                Increase show count</button>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import data from './data'


export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(2); // initial count to show initial items
  
  const addMore = () => {  // function that will make count add by 2 to show 2 more items  
    setCount(count+2);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.slice(0,count).map(({title}) =>   
        (<h3>{title}</h3>))}  
      <button onClick={addMore}>  // onClick call addMore function add we get 2 more items
        Add More
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Explanation:

[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function is used to slice the array upto `count`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, to paginate and slice the posts data

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PostData from '../data/posts.json'

    class PostList extends Component {
      state = {
        posts: [],
        perPage: 10,
        lastPostIndex: 0,
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        const { lastPostIndex, perPage } = this.state;

        getPosts(lastPostIndex);
      }

      getPosts(from) {
        const { perPage } = this.state;

        this.setState({
          posts: PostData.slice(from, from + perPage),
          lastPostIndex: from
        });
      }

      render () {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            {PostData.map((postDetail, index) => {
              return <h2>{postDetailDetail.title}</h2>
            })}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return first 10 results like this as well. No unwanted data just first 10 filtered posts.

```
{PostData.filter((item, i) => i < 10).map((postDetail, index) => {
 return <h2>{postDetail.title}</h2> 
})}
```